# Show app and device info in email message body - swift

Tags: ios, swift, email

How does this convert to swift? Minimum I need is the app name, app version and locale or country appended to the email message.

```
NSString *appName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
UIDevice *currentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *model = [currentDevice model];
NSString *systemVersion = [currentDevice systemVersion];
NSArray *languageArray = [NSLocale preferredLanguages];
NSString *language = [languageArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *country = [locale localeIdentifier];
NSString *appVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nApp Name: %@ \nModel: %@ \nSystem Version: %@ \nLanguage: %@ \nCountry: %@ \nApp Version: %@", appName, model, systemVersion, language, country, appVersion];
```

So far I've found

```
let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as! String
```

though have had no luck adding that to message body.

This is what I have so far.

```
@IBAction func sendMail(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let recipients = ["support@enquinn.rocks"]
    let title = "App feedback"
    let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as! String


    let message = ""

    let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mc.setToRecipients(recipients)
    mc.setSubject(title)
    mc.setMessageBody(message, isHTML: false)

    self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You have not converted any of the code, your `message` is just empty string. Convert all the code and then post a question where not succeeding

Comment: Yes, I realise that though don't know how to add it. Plus I'm asking for help to convert the code.

Comment: You have not translated the Objective-C to swift, just one line and you missing the hole part where `stringWithFormat:` is used to create the message. Thus you question looks a lot like, I have this code you please create the Swift version of it. These kind of questions are frowned upon and get downvoted. So translate every Obj-c line to Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path. If you're on Swift 4 you can use a multi-string literal and format your message like so:

```
let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as! String
let appVersion = "5"


let message = """
App name: \(appName)
Version: \(appVersion)
"""
```

**Swift 3 version:**

```
let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as! String
let appVersion = "5"

var message = "App name: \(appName)\n"
message += "Version: \(appVersion)"
```

I just hardcoded your appVersion in the example above since you asked specifically how to insert your variables into your message. Hope that helps.

Comment: That's what I'm after though I'm on Swift 3 and that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I added a version for Swift 3.